# How to get main picture of an event with Meetup API V3

Tags: meetup

I am trying to switch from Meetup API V2 to V3 as V2 will be deprecated soon. However, I can't find a way to get main picture of an event with that new version.

With APi V2, I was able to get the main picture with `/2/events` and a link to the picture of events where returned in the Json answer as `photo_url`.
However, with V3, no photo url is returned.

I have been trying to use `/:urlname/events` to get event id and then `/:urlname/events/:event_id/photos`however, the request, using the Meetup online test console, returns an empty result.